# Bash: Is it possible to set environment variables for a single sub-process by evaluating a command?

Tags: bash, shell

This works perfectly fine:

```sh
>$ ENV=var printenv
ENV=var
```

This also works but it sets the environment variable for the entire shell:

```sh
>$ export $(echo ENV=var)

>$ printenv
ENV=var
```

I would like to do something like this but it fails:

```sh
>$ $(echo ENV=var) printenv
bash: ENV=var: command not found
```

Is there another way to pass environment variables to a single sub-process by evaluating a command?

Comment: what is the problem with the first solution?

Comment: Oh the first solution was just meant to be for clarification what I mean with setting environment variables for a single sub-process. I would like to be able to generate them programmatically by evaluating a command. `$(echo ENV=var)` is just an example here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `env`.

```
env "$(echo ENV=var)" printenv
```

Or use `eval` but know how to safely use it.

```
eval "$(echo ENV=var)" printenv
```

Either way in both commands you have to make sure the output is sanitized.